# Read JSON data with Java-based Processing language

Tags: java, json, processing

I am using [Processing language](https://processing.org/) to read a json file, parse it, and store some values in local objects. However, my problem is how to read the values when I don't know the keys.
e.g: When I provide the keys I can read it like this:

```
String[] Keys ={"key1","key2"};
JSONArray json = loadJSONArray(filename);
int noItems = json.size();  
JSONArray[] list = new JSONArray[noItems];
list[i] = json.getJSONArray(Keys[i]);
```

However, since I cannot always know the keys, I want to be able to read the data.
Since processing language is based on Java, I tried using an iterator to go through the file, but I got a compiler error saying that it's not possible to convert the object to iterator. These are my unsuccessful attempts so far:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
...
Iterator<String> keys= json.iterator().keys();
Iterator i = json.iterator();
Iterator<?> keys = json.values();
```

Can anyone please help me find an effective/dynamic way of reading the json file using this language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [this documentation reference](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/data/JSONObject.html) it says that there are two methods which produce:

- An iterator for keys: [JSONObject::keyIterator](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/data/JSONObject.html#keyIterator--)
- A set of all keys: [JSONObject::keys](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/data/JSONObject.html#keys--)

Pick the one you want and good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Based on answers, this is a simple way to read and parse a json file:

```
  json = loadJSONObject(filename);
  JSONObject o = (JSONObject) json;   

  Set keyset = o.keys();
  Iterator<String> keys = keyset.iterator();

  while( keys.hasNext() ) {    
      String key = (String)keys.next();
      JSONArray newlist = o.getJSONArray(key);
  }
```